# Is there a way to not italicize a word in a \textit{} expression?

Tags: formatting, italic

I would like to have a sentence like this:

> *In the* Smith *case, the Supreme Court held...*

where the entire sentence is in italics except for "Smith" since it is the short name of a case. (You can imagine many other examples like this with movies, etc.)

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
\textit{In the \textit{Smith} case, the Supreme Court held...}
```

However, the above code makes everything italics. Is there something I can do to make Smith non-italicized without resorting to the below code?

```
\textit{In the} Smith \textit{case, the Supreme Court held...}
```

The only problem I have with that piece of code is that it makes editing problematic if I decide that I'd rather have "Smith" at another place in the sentence.

I appreciate any and all help -- even if the help is simply that the solution I want does not exist.

Comment: Upright is the same of the font shape you want. `\textup{}`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That's *exactly* what `\emph` does:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\emph{In the \emph{Smith} case, the Supreme Court held\dots}

\end{document}
```

or, if you prefer to manually control that, then you can use `\textup`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\textit{In the \textup{Smith} case, the Supreme Court held\dots}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Solution worked. Thank you! I wasn't aware of `\emph` before and couldn't find the solution via a Google search.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use:

```
    \textit{This is my text, but I want {\normalfont this} to not be in italics.}
```