# Can't remove italic format from my text with either \normalfont or \textnormal

Tags: fonts, r, pandoc, markdown

```
$$\textit{Some italic and {\normalfont non italic} text}$$
$$\textit{Some italic and \textnormal{non italic} text}$$
```

My LaTeX block above is supposed to generate text like this (the first line):

[image: expected]

But when I put that into my workflow (R Markdown -> Pandoc -> HTML) it comes out looking like this (the white font output below). What is going wrong? Seems nothing is recognizing my `\normalfont` or `\textnormal` arguments.

[image: actual]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by placing a text sentence in a display-math setting?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451247/134574

Comment: Are you typesetting your test document with LaTeX or with pandoc? If it's the latter, your posting will be closed as off-topic for this site.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with Pandoc converting the Markdown. `$$\textit{Some italic and \textup{non italic} text}$$` doesn't work either. My IDE is R Studio, which runs my text through Pandoc to output to HTML. Not sure if that answers your question @Mico.

Comment: Why are you adding the $$ around the text?

Comment: Using `$$` or `\[` with `\]` is how you tell R Studio IDE you're writing a LaTeX equation. Ultimately I need to write a formula that is `ABC = minimum{XYZ, ZYX}`. I don't want the "minimum" italicized, but LaTeX italicizes everything by default in math it seems. Utilizing the method in my question "should" work, but it doesn't, probably because I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: You are in math, and math you should use math font commands and not text font commands. E.g. `\[\mathit{ABC} = \mathrm{minimum}{\mathit{XYZ}, \mathit{ZYX}}\]
`

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer your answer worked. Thank you. Can you put that as a solution? I'll wait the required 24 hours then can mark as solved. I'll be glad to hear any expanded explanation as well if you want to provide this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $$ you are entering math mode. And in math mode you should use math fonts and math switches.

```
 \[\mathit{ABC} = \mathrm{minimum}{\mathit{XYZ}, \mathit{ZYX}}\]
```

Comment: Anything wrong with using this instead? `\[ABC = \mathrm{minimum}\{XYZ, ZYX\}\]`. Isn't putting `\mathit{}` redundant since `\mathit{}` is default behavior inside `\[` and `\]`?